# How do I spawn a process and ignore all user prompts?

Tags: python, user-input, subprocess

I'm trying to automate mounting and unmounting of [UNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) drives with Python on Windows. I'm using the `subprocess` module to the execute the various commands so I can log their output. However, the `NET USE` command occasionally prompts the user for input (like a password). Usually things work well, but since I am using `subprocess.communicate()`, my program hangs indefinitely when `NET USE` asks my "subprocess" for input. Of course, I have no idea it's asking for input. It just sits there waiting patiently and making me frustrated.

This is a more general problem than just `NET USE`, so please don't go that route. There are other instances where some (other) program asks for input and my program freezes. Any thoughts?

Comment: From the docs I see that "`communicate()` returns a tuple `(stdoutdata, stderrdata)`".  Does the prompt not show up in `stdoutdata`?

Comment: `communicate()` also waits until the program is done.

Comment: To deal with prompts rather than ignore them you may want to check out winpexpect https://bitbucket.org/geertj/winpexpect/wiki/Home.

Comment: Can you provide a username and password to NET USE when you launch the command as listed here: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/71576-net-use-userdomainusername-password/ ?

Comment: Yeah, actually I was able to solve my issue with `NET USE` by supplying `/YES`. But the general problem still remains.

Comment: Well, you either handle this at the command level, or by using pexpect/winpexpect.  Subprocess doesn't handle this kind of thing.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: You're right. If you sum up your remarks and post them as an answer, I'll give it the green check. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some programs are smart and realize that if there is no way for a user to input anything, then they shouldn't even ask. For such programs, you can add "stdin=open('/dev/null')" to the subprocess.Popen options.

In the more difficult case, where the program really insists on interacting, all you can do is provide the interaction yourself.

EDIT: I should mention that the pexpect library is a great way to do such interaction.